# Can I tell Typescript that both of a method's input parameters are of the same type?

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```
foo(first: string, second: string) {
  // ..
}
```

Do I have to write **string** twice, or could I tell Typescript that; 
*"hey, both of these parameters are of the same type"*.

Comment: yes you have to write `string` twice

Comment: I wish it wasn't so :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to declare the type of each parameter as the `first` and `second` parameter have nothing in common. You must declare their type explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would argue though, that they do have something in common - their type!

Comment: @haugan so?  code should be written to be clear.  if you want to propose a change to the language, you can do so, but make a better case for it than wanting to save a few keystrokes.  *you* know they're the same type, the compiler is dumb and stupid.  You have to tell it what it doesn't know.

Comment: @Amy If you imagine a lot more parameters, and writing the same type definition many times over the course of several years - we're no longer talking "a few keystrokes". But, I guess this is what objects are for - encapsulating all those parameters so I don't have to write every type for each method that needs them?

Comment: @haugan In certain cases it makes sense to pass arrays or objects or arrays of objects to functions. A common rule of thumb is that a function should have at most 3 parameters. And while writing the type definition may seem tedious, it pays of by catching potential bugs (well, in typescript only during compile-time not run-time), and if you use a proper IDE, e.g. webstorm, auto-completion becomes your friend.

Comment: @k0pernikus Oh, yeah that makes sense - cheers! Webstorm really is excellent by the way. I tried to write in VS Code for a while, but Webstorm's auto-completion is miles ahead (at least in the Angular/Typescript world)!